# How can you get a screenshot from someone's web browser?

Tags: language-agnostic

I didn't think this was possible, but http://www.snapabug.com provides a service that uses screen capture technology to generate reports that helps you help your users. How are they able to do this??

Apparently, their service does not require any extra browser plugins or extensions. My guess is that it uses Flash, since this doesn't seem possible in JavaScript, and loading a Java applet is ridiculously slow.

Comment: They probably use "print screen" and use the content of the clipboard.

Comment: nice idea oded, never thought it could be done.

Comment: I didn't know JavaScript could manipulate images in the clipboard. From my understanding of JavaScript's clipboard facilities, they're pretty weak in practice, because browsers disable those capabilities for security reasons. Even then, I thought only manipulating text contents was possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SnapABug uses a Java Applet to get the screenshot of the Browser.  A Java Runtime Environment is [listed as one of the Technical Requirements](http://www.snapabug.com/faq#requirements).

[This blog post](http://www.barklund.org/blog/2009/10/14/how-snapabug-works/) details how the Java Applet captures the image from the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the links! I got an email directly from the CTO confirming that they use a Java applet.