# How to programatically take snapshot of browser rendered image in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

I have an image rendered by browser. I want to provide a functionality to my clients wherein they can just click a button and the JavaScript code should take the snapshot of the screen image (Screen) and prompt the users with "Save As" option.
I am using IE.

Can anyone kindly help me with this?

Comment: What does "image rendered by browser" mean exactly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Take a screenshot of a webpage with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do that with plain javascript due to security restrictions (imagine if a site could take a snapshot of your banking details).

Since you mentioned that you are targeting Internet Explorer, you can do it with an ActiveX control as mentioned in this answer: [Take a screenshot of a webpage with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript).

Alternatively, you can use a java applet as mentioned in this answer: [How can you get a screenshot from someone's web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386382/how-can-you-get-a-screenshot-from-someones-web-browser)